# SQL Injection Threat with PHP Forms?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I was trying to demonstrate the need for prepared statements in PHP, but I came into a bit of a problem because PHP does some conveniently strange things with strings passed in through forms.

The statement I'm trying to "break" is a simple:

`SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'`

But doing something like passing in `X' or TRUE;--` for the password doesn't actually work because PHP automatically escapes the single-quote and turns the statement into:

`SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = 'X\' or TRUE;--'`

And the password equality remains intact because of the escaped single-quote. Is this statement considered safe? How can it be broken, if not?

Comment: Personally I'd MD5 the password from the form to avoid injection and then compare it to the password in the database. That's just me though.

Comment: @WilliamIsted: Yeah, I use SHA-2 when working with real applications; this is just a hypothetical query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have magic quotes turned on. I would definitely not consider that statement safe, as if you were to move it to a server running PHP 5.4, it would be completely vulnerable. Magic quotes has been a deprecated feature for a long time, and it can mess up other parts of the application, so don't rely on it.

To demonstrate, just set `magic_quotes_gpc = Off` in php.ini.

Comment: If you add something about the mysql extension being dead and using PDO, this should become the accepted answer.

Comment: Interesting! I was trying to show a friend who's relatively new to PHP why they needed them, but I failed to give them a password to try which would bypass their log-in form. Then I tested out what the SQL query was doing on my own server and saw it had the same behaviour. Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have Magic Quotes enabled in your PHP environment. It will automatically escape strings, however they are deprecated and should not be used. They are not a cure, they are a patch. You are much better of using proper sanitation methods like `mysql_real_escape_string`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php

Edit: Also prepared statements!

Other "unsafe" safe functions in PHP:

`addslashes` - you might think it's safe, but it doesn't filter out multibyte characters that could cause injection.

Comment: Or rather, PDO, as mentioned in the question ;)

Comment: mysql_* should not be used anymore!